# Create Oracle partitioning table without PK

Tags: performance, oracle, partitioning

We have a huge table which are 144 million rows available right now and also increasing 1 million rows each day.

I would like to create a partitioning table on Oracle 11G server but I am not aware of the techniques. So I have two question :

1. Is it possible to create a partitioning table from a table that don't have PK?
2. What is your suggestion to create a partitioning table like huge records?

Comment: What is the current structure of the table and how do you normally query it? Also why doesn't it have a PK? Is there a unique set of columns on the table?

Comment: Dear Ben, we have 24 stores. Each store has own SQL Server. Due to the performance problem, each month removing previous month record. Therefore, time to time coming non-unique records from SQL server. That is why we created a non PK table on Oracle. There are several non-unique index on the table. But, the performance is realy terrible! Just simple count function was return result after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but keep in mind that the partition key must be a part of PK
2. Avoid global indexes
3. Chose right partitioning key - have it prepared for some kind of future maintenance ( cutting off oldest or unnecessary partitions, placing them in separate tablespaces... etc)

There are too many things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

> "There are several non-unique index on the table. But, the performance
>   is realy terrible! Just simple count function was return result after
>   5 minutes."

Partitioning is not necessarily a performance enhancer.  The partition key will allow  certain queries to benefit from partition pruning i.e. those queries which drive off the partition key in the WHERE clause.  Other queries may perform worse, if there WHERE clause runs against the grain of the partition key,

It is difficult to give specific advice because the details you've posted are so vague.  But here are some other possible ways of speeding up queries on big tables:

- index compression
- parallel query
- better, probably compound, indexes.

Comment: Dear @APC, our data available in our company head quarter on Terradata which is 33 countries using this database at the same time. Due to the network latency, time to time we can't quick query on Terradata. Therefore, we would like to do backup database in our Country. What kind of info that you need? Please be more specific.